# Could you please help on Airflow Job at every 15th minute of the hour?

Tags: cron, airflow

Could you please provide the help on running the Airflow job to be scheduled at running every 15th minute of the hour. Let say if the job runs at 12:15, next would be 1:15 AM, 2:15 AM so on.

I tried with schedule_interval='15 * * * *' but no luck

Comment: The cron syntax is correct. Is this or any other dag running at all in first place? Additionaly, are your webserver/scheduler/triggerer/worker running properly?

Answer (score 0):

`15 * * * *` is the correct cron expression to schedule every 15th minute of the hour.

Answer (score 0):

The Best Solution Will be
*/15 * * * *
and you can use this website to check it
https://crontab.guru/#*/15_*_*_*_*

Comment: That runs every 15 minutes. That's not what OP asked for.